# Change matplotlib backend in Python virtualenv

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, virtualenv, backend

I've installed a `virtualenv` with [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) using Python v2.7.12. Inside this virtualenv, I installed `matplotlib` v1.5.1 via:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

with no issues. The problem is that a simple

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter([], [])
plt.show()
```

script fails to produce a plot window. The backend that I see in the virtualenv using:

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.rcParams['backend']
```

is `agg`, which is apparently the root cause of the issue. If I check the backend in my system-wide installation, I get `Qt4Agg` (and the above script when run shows a plot window just fine).

There are already several similar questions in SO, and I've tried the solutions given in all of them.

1. [Matplotlib plt.show() isn't showing graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688409/matplotlib-plt-show-isnt-showing-graph)

   Tried to create the virtualenv with the [--system-site-packages](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/?highlight=system%20site#cmdoption--system-site-packages) option. No go.
2. [How to ensure matplotlib in a Python 3 virtualenv uses the TkAgg backend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785505/how-to-ensure-matplotlib-in-a-python-3-virtualenv-uses-the-tkagg-backend)

   Installed `sudo apt install tk-dev`, then re-installed using `pip --no-cache-dir install -U --force-reinstall matplotlib`. The backend still shows as `agg`.
3. [Matplotlib doesn't display graph in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054718/matplotlib-doesnt-display-graph-in-virtualenv)

   Followed install instructions given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16856545/1391441), did nothing (the other answer involves using `easy_install`, which [I will not do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/1391441))
4. [matplotlib plot window won't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear)

   The solution given here is to *"install a GUI library (one of Tkinter, GTK, QT4, PySide, Wx)"*. I don't know how to do this. Furthermore, if I use:

   ```
   import matplotlib.rcsetup as rcsetup
   print(rcsetup.all_backends)
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   [u'GTK', u'GTKAgg', u'GTKCairo', u'MacOSX', u'Qt4Agg', u'Qt5Agg', u'TkAgg', u'WX', u'WXAgg', u'CocoaAgg', u'GTK3Cairo', u'GTK3Agg', u'WebAgg', u'nbAgg', u'agg', u'cairo', u'emf', u'gdk', u'pdf', u'pgf', u'ps', u'svg', u'template']
   ```

   meaning that all those backends *are* available in my system (?).
5. [matplotlib does not show my drawings although I call pyplot.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show)

   My `matplotlibrc` file shows the line:

   ```
   backend      : Qt4Agg
   ```

   I don't know how to make the virtualenv aware of this?

Some of the solutions involve creating links to the system version of `matplotlib` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32439941/1391441) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780169/1391441)), which I don't want to do. I want to use the version of `matplotlib` installed in the `virtualenv`.

If I try to set the backend with:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTKAgg')
```

I get `ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed` (same with `GTK`). But if I do `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2 python-gtk2-dev`, I see that they are both installed.

Using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

(or `Qt5Agg`) results in `ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5, or PySide package to be installed, but it was not found.` Not sure if I should install some package?

Using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

results in `ImportError: No module named _tkinter`, but `sudo apt-get install python-tk` says that it is installed.

Using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTKCairo')
```

results in `ImportError: No module named gtk`. So I try `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev` but it says that it already installed.

How can I make the virtualenv use the same backend that my system is using?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious workaround of setting a backend manually? [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249447/5067311).

Comment: @AndrasDeak please see updated answer.

Comment: Well, that's pretty odd, since [at least tkinter should be installed, probably](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20075485/5067311). Unfortunately I don't know anything about virtualenvs, so I can't help beyond this point.

Comment: Tkintir *is* installed. But the virtualenv somehow does not see it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that I understand. But python should be installed within the virtualenv itself, so I'd expect at least tkinter to work within the virtualenv:) Even if for some reason it fails to see all the other modules installed with apt.

Comment: @Gabriel I am the author of the answer to the second question you posted. I just tried my own answer for Python 2 and I can confirm it doesn't work as you said (it does work for Python 3 though). Let me get back to you if I can figure out what is happening.

Comment: @Gabriel I think I figured it out and I posted an answer that worked for me. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: "results in ImportError: No module named _tkinter, but sudo apt-get install python-tk says that it is installed." - This is because the apt-get install affected the **system Python only**. If your virtual environment is based off a different Python, that Python needs to have Tkinter support (i.e., be recompiled with support). If it's based off the system Python, you may need to re-create the virtual environment after the system Python update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider changing your backend to `TkAgg` in the Python 2 virtualenv by running the following:

```
sudo apt install python-tk  # install Python 2 bindings for Tk
pip --no-cache-dir install -U --force-reinstall matplotlib  # reinstall matplotlib
```

To confirm the backend is indeed `TkAgg`, run

```
python -c 'import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.get_backend())'
```

and you should see `TkAgg`.

Comment: I need some help in doing this in a conda environment. I want to change to 'GTKAgg' backend, and in my conda env pygtk is installed, but I still got the `Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed` error. Re-installing matplotlib doesn't help.

Comment: @Jason You might want to ask a new question since this answer may not apply to conda environments.